# Getting error "Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication..." on one server while working on another

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I know this error has been discussed many a times but I couldn't find any answers relevant to me so am trying again.

Basically, I have a WCF service, which I have deployed to on one of our servers and it works fine with Windows Authentication. However, when I move the same server to a different server, I get the following error

"Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service"

I have checked the bindings and they seem to be configured fine. They are as below

> ```
>     <bindings>
>         <basicHttpBinding>
>             <binding name="basicHttpBindingConfig">
>                 <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
>                     <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
>                 </security>
>             </binding>
>         </basicHttpBinding>
>     </bindings>
> ```

I have also compared the machine.config and applicationHost.config files on the two servers and they seem similar.

Any pointers / help would be really appreciated.

Regards,

Hamid

Answer (score 0):

Got the resolved by doing a repair of .Net 4.5 on the server.

As a background, I had to remove certain features from the IIS server and had to run aspnet_regiis -i on top of it to re-register ASP.Net.

I was getting the above mentioned error. Re-installing .Net Framework 4.5 fixed it.